# JAVA Change JSESSIONID cookie

Tags: java, session, wicket, jsessionid

I'm using JAVA and Wicket on JBOSS 5.
I need to change JSESSIONID cookie value to get the same Session used in another client (setting the other client's JSESSIONID). I need that to authenticate the other client that has no keyboard).
What is the best way?

Comment: Consider using URL tracking

Comment: Are you sure? I sense somebody snooping for client's credentials (by stealing their authentication token)! :p

Comment: That sounds like a horible idea. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* want to hack the `JSESSIONID` (**which I don't recommend**), you can do the following way:

- Write a Servlet Filter
- In that filter write a wrapper for the `HttpServletRequest` (a new instance of this class must be passed to the `chain.doFilter()`) (let's call it `RequestWrapper`)
- In the `RequestWrapper` override the `getSession(boolean)` method

In the `getSession(booelan)` implementation you have to

- Identify (and remember) the session you want to 'share' with the non-keyboard user (this should come first)
- Identify the situation when you want to make the 'change' (when with some kind of check you identify your non-keyboard user)
- When you have to 'change', you can return the *remembered* session from the `getSession()`

The key moment is: **How do you identify your non-keyboard user?** If you can't do it safely (from the current information you provided I cannot see it), it is a **security hole**.

Comment: I tried this solution but there's a bit more to tell... the application has many server so I'm not sure the request goes always on the same one. The idea is that the non-keyboard client shows the sessionID, then I'll use that sessionID in another client with keyboard to authenticate the user and I'll save the information on the Session object. The non-keyboard user - that is polling the server - will be authenticated as soon as it'll find the information on the session object

Comment: let's continue on the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23573/java-change-jsessionid-cookie

Comment: human user and machine user are in 2 different locations/browser so they'll connect maybe to 2 different instances of the server.

Comment: ok, this is the step I'm not able to do: >>Let the machine send requests with JSESSIONID (you can set the cookie). I can't set that cookie bacause after I set it, jboss overrides it.

Comment: If you set the JSESSIONID cookie from your application, it will not work. I am talking that you could set the JSESSIONID from the client.

Comment: I was thinking over this whole situation. Session Replication will not give you the solution, because it will replicate the `Session`, so *JBoss* can fetch it from `SessionManager`. But there will not be any request, which would go through your `Filter`, so you *cannot save the session reference*. What I an recommending now is **you should have 1 monitor client for EACH server, DIRECLY calling that server instance**. This way you wil have a `Session` on each server for sure, so the `Filter` can find the `Session` reference on each server.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to implement some kind of **auto-login feature** in your application. There are a number of possibilities for that (**Client Certificate**, or **Single Sign-On** with some other AA provider, even domain cookie).

If you are trying to log in with another application, your options are **HTTP Basic Authentication**, Client Certificate, or simply posting the username/password to your login page (this one is not the safest, though).

I prefer the **Client Certificate**, since that is the safest solution.

Comment: I can't use any of these solution.. the only way I see is to change the current JSESSIONID, is it possible in jboss?

Comment: All I know is that it would be a gaping security hole if it was possible.

Comment: Why cannot you use any kind of auto-login feature to the app? putting HTTP Basic auth for a specific unused URL (e.g /autologin) could be a good solution.