# modify the requested session id in a HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

How can I modify the `"requestedSessionId"` attribute in a `HttpServletRequest` ?

```
public class MySecurityContextPersistenceFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            httpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId();
            //Modify this value ?
        }

    }
```

The reason why I'm trying to do this, is that my client application does not handle Cookies..

So the session Id is sent in the `"body"` instead, and that's where I want to get my `JSESSIONID` from and set it in the request so it can be handled later by `SpringSecurityFilterChain`.

Comment: Why aren't use using url-encoding if the client does not accept cookies?

Comment: Bacause I don't know what this is :) Does it allow passing session id in the URL ?

Comment: When the client does not support cookies the session ID is encoded in the URL.All you need to do is use this api:http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: yes i just figured that out with `;jsessionid=` parameter. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that.

Here [JAVA Change JSESSIONID cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562477/java-change-jsessionid-cookie/14562844#14562844) we walked around this topic, there are partial solutions, but all depends on your goals.

Comment: thank you. My goal is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096764/implementing-spring-security-with-java-client and all I could think about is set the session id manually from the request.

Comment: how can I use the URL to pass the session id instead? `disable-url-rewriting="false"` doesn't seem tp do any good (tesing with a browser with disabled cookies) ?